# Criar colunas no R a partir de outra onde alguns valores são nulos

Tags: r

Estou querendo criar uma coluna a partir de outra no R, onde parte das linhas não apresentam valor. A coluna deverá ser construída da seguinte maneira: se a linha da coluna base tem valor, ela buscará esse mesmo valor, caso contrário ele deve buscar a informação da linha anterior dessa nova coluna. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: você tentou algo?

Comment: Cristiane, coloque um exemplo ilustrando o resultado esperado, isso ajuda a eliminar a ambiguidade da pergunta. Veja aqui exemplo de como melhorar a pergunta. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/825#825

Comment: Olá, Cristiane, se a resposta do Rodrigo atendeu à sua dúvida, você pode aceitá-la clinado no símbolo de ok ao lado esquerdo da resposta!

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar a função `na.locf` do pacote `zoo`. Exemplo:

```r
library(zoo)
x <- c(1, NA, NA, 2, NA, 3, 4)
na.locf(x)
```

Resultado:

```r
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa apenas com funções do base que poderia ser usado para outros valores além de NA:

```
x <- c(1, NA, NA, 2, NA, 3, 4)

nao_eh_na <- !is.na(x)
x_indices <- cumsum(nao_eh_na)
x_vals <- x[nao_eh_na]

x_vals[x_indices]
```

Resultado:

```
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4
```